# ArcGIS Online producing isochrones which are skewed North-South, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-online, isochrone, drive-time-areas

I am trying to run an isochrone analysis in ArcGIS Online using `Analysis > Use Proximity > Create Drive-Time Areas`.

The resulting polygons are stretched North-South, I suspect this is due to the analysis being done in WGS 84 instead of a projected coordinate system.

Is there a way to fix this? Possibly by running the analysis using a projected coordinate system?

**EDIT:**

As per Vince's request:

I used the `Create Drive-Time Areas` analysis tool with the following parameters:

- Walking Time (5 minutes)
- Towards Facility
- Areas from different points - Overlap
- Use current map extent - Unchecked

There is no option available to specify performing geodesic calculations.

The study area is at approximately 53° North.

Comment: Analysis is generally done in the units in which the data is stored.

Comment: @Vince the point data I uploaded as the origin is in the correct projected coordinate system.

Comment: On-the-fly reprojection is expensive. Is the hosted copy in the default Web Mercator or as a WGS84 geographic CS?

Comment: I think it's in Web Mercator but the actual shapefile I uploaded was in my local projection system

Comment: Your question asserts that a geographic projection would skew to the north, but in fact, it would be Web Mercator which could do so.  Please [Edit] the question to give details of the options you used (especially if offered the option to perform geodesic calculations), and of the extent of the data processing.  Note that, since locations near the pole are smaller in area per square degree, it's not unexpected that distances would increase visually to the north.

Comment: @Vince - I have editing the question as requested. Do you think performing the analysis on data in WGS84 would produce a better result?